# Why does this recorded signal have two waveforms in it?

Tags: matlab, filters, signal-analysis, audio

I have recorded the two words "Stop" and "Go" in the waveform. There is an orange waveform and any normal assumption would be the noise picked up by the receiver, but my professor asked "If the orange waveform is indeed noise, why is it not mixed up with the original signal and have stood out like a separate signal?"

[image]

Please provide an explanation for that waveform.

Comment: I'll just throw a hint here as I believe this to be somewhat "trivial" to provide an answer for. You could think of various occasions where you have two (simultaneous) signals in a file and how they were acquired. More hints: Reproduction formats...

Comment: Is it because I recorded in a phone which has dual channel recorder? Because of it, i am getting the audio in 2 different channels, each representing the signal gain as much they could record?

Comment: Well, I would say that you are spot on! It's as trivial as it can get.... Two waveforms means......... two channels. There's no other way (at least known to me) to get two different waveforms without having two distinct channels (with an exception being beamforming maybe).

Comment: please show the matlab code used for such recording.